# How to get number of connections on PORT per IP in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I have been searching around Google for some time and I can`t seem to find an answer...

I am using **GetExtendedTcpTable()** to view my current connections, but I am unable to get the number of connections that each IP does on a specific PORT.

Is there any example/function for this ? Or do I have to create something ?

Any guidance or example is much appreciated.

Have a nice day!

Comment: You'll have to walk the `TCP_TABLE_BASIC_CONNECTIONS` table and calculate the number of connections to a specific port yourself - there's no built-in API to give you this summary data automatically; and calculating it should be relatively easy.

Comment: @Petesh Thank you for this information, I will try to mockup something!

Comment: @Petesh At the moment I'm using TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL

Comment: It will return some extra information than the table I mentioned, but the act of determining the values you're looking for would be the same.

Comment: @Petesh Indeed I'm confused, I think there is needed a separate list to store IP's and PORTS, then do the check ?

Comment: If anyone else can provide me with an example I would appreciate it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using [this code from MSDN as the basis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366917(v=vs.85).aspx) we end up with this example which enumerates a list of connections, populating the pointer to int `ports` with the number of connections from remote systems to the local ports.

To determine the number of connections to a particular local port, you can simply print out the value of `ports[port]`.

The code as supplied is very much more `C`, than `C++`, I just used a `new[]` and `delete[]` for the ports.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define MALLOC(x) calloc(1, (x))
#define FREE(x) free((x))

int main()
{
    // Declare and initialize variables
    PMIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID pTcpTable;
    int *ports; // an array of all the possible ports
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;

    char szRemoteAddr[128];

    struct in_addr IpAddr;

    int i;

    ports = new int[1 << (sizeof(u_short) * 8)]();

    pTcpTable = (MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID *)MALLOC(sizeof(MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID));
    if (pTcpTable == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    dwSize = sizeof(MIB_TCPTABLE);
    // Make an initial call to GetTcpTable to
    // get the necessary size into the dwSize variable
    if ((dwRetVal = GetExtendedTcpTable(pTcpTable, &dwSize, TRUE, AF_INET, TCP_TABLE_BASIC_CONNECTIONS, 0)) ==
        ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
        FREE(pTcpTable);
        pTcpTable = (MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID *)MALLOC(dwSize);
        if (pTcpTable == NULL) {
            printf("Error allocating memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    // Make a second call to GetTcpTable to get
    // the actual data we require
    if ((dwRetVal = GetExtendedTcpTable(pTcpTable, &dwSize, TRUE, AF_INET, TCP_TABLE_BASIC_CONNECTIONS, 0)) == NO_ERROR) {
        printf("\tNumber of entries: %d\n", (int)pTcpTable->dwNumEntries);
        for (i = 0; i < (int)pTcpTable->dwNumEntries; i++) {
            printf("\n\tTCP[%d] State: %ld - ", i,
                pTcpTable->table[i].dwState);
            if (pTcpTable->table[i].dwState != MIB_TCP_STATE_ESTAB)
                continue;

            // get the port in host order
            u_short port = ntohs((u_short)pTcpTable->table[i].dwLocalPort);
            ports[port] += 1; // increment this port

            IpAddr.S_un.S_addr = (u_long)pTcpTable->table[i].dwRemoteAddr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &IpAddr, szRemoteAddr, sizeof(szRemoteAddr));
            printf("\tTCP[%d] Remote Addr: %s:%d\n", i, szRemoteAddr, ntohs((u_short)pTcpTable->table[i].dwRemotePort));
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("\tGetExtendedTcpTable failed with %d\n", dwRetVal);
        FREE(pTcpTable);
        delete[] ports;
        return 1;
    }

    if (pTcpTable != NULL) {
        FREE(pTcpTable);
        pTcpTable = NULL;
    }
    delete[] ports;
    return 0;
}
```

Now if you wanted a list of the remote addresses coming to a port, then you could make a `std::vector<std::string> remote_addresses` and perform a `remote_addresses.push_back(szRemoteAddr)` when you determined that the port was correct.

There is a potential race condition where between the initial call to `GetExtendedTcpTable` and the subsequent call to `GetExtendedTcpTable` another connection comes in, which increases the value of `dwSize`. Generally asking for more memory helps in this case to just prevent this from being an issue - i.e. after the initial call, try asking for 8K more than you need - it's not likely to be a big issue, though.

Comment: Thank you, I allready had something like this to list all the connections, but my problem begin when I try to "detect" how many connection does 1 Remote IP to a certain port...